# Problems with Mutex Locking in Go

Tags: concurrency, go, mutex, goroutine

Everything works great apart from the mutex. After I lock and unlock, it won't do anything. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

On top of this, after unlocking, I want to run a function inside this function. I've tried just calling it as a regular function (timer()) and even (go timer()).

```
func shield(state *State){
    for s := range state.ToggleShield { //run if data on channel
        if s == true { //if data on channel is true
            fmt.Println("Opening the shields This is uninteruptable. Please wait...")

            state.VariableMutex.Lock()
            state.Finished = false //disable other commands
            state.VariableMutex.Unlock()

            fmt.Println("Move!!")
            ticker := time.Tick(time.Second)
            for i := 10; i >= 0; i-- {
                <-ticker
                fmt.Printf("\rOn 10/%d", i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please supply a minimal code snippet that compiles? Also, try https://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code

Comment: It's a bit of mess because I'm working on it but https://play.golang.org/p/M0iR3G6oUu

Comment: that doesn't seem minimal, and a question's "meat" must be in the question itself anyway

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding what you're trying to do, but maybe instead of using this `Finished` variable you should put in mutual exclusion the full operation, i.e: `Lock` the mutex when you set `Finished = true` , and Unlock it when the operation finish. For what I see, you're only putting in mutual exclusion the modifications of `Finished` variable.

Answer (score 4):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Go statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)
>
> A "go" statement starts the execution of a function call as an
>   independent concurrent thread of control, or goroutine, within the
>   same address space.
>
> The function value and parameters are evaluated as usual in the
>   calling goroutine, but unlike with a regular call, program execution
>   does not wait for the invoked function to complete. Instead, the
>   function begins executing independently in a new goroutine. When the
>   function terminates, its goroutine also terminates.

Your program does not appear to have proper mechanisms to wait until your goroutines complete: "program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete." To demonstrate this, I inserted a crude wait mechanism at the end of your program `main` function:

```
// wait for a while to give goroutines a chance to complete
time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
```

Program: https://play.golang.org/p/ODdEihip4m

Output:

```
Toggling Shield
Opening the shields This is uninteruptable. Please wait...
Move!!

On 10/10
On 10/9
On 10/8
On 10/7
On 10/6

Program exited.
```